# Is there a way to check if the files in the Windows Defender Offline Scanner folder are corrupted?

Tags: windows-10, security, file-permissions, file-corruption, windows-defender

On a Windows 10 PC, I opened the folder "...ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Offline Scanner" clicking 'continue' to allow access, not thinking at the time that it would allow any program running on my account access also.

Is there a way I can verify the integrity of the Defender Offline files, in case anything accessed them that shouldn't have?

Details:

- Unplugged internet about 2 hours after accessing folder.
- Few hours later changed the folder permissions back, unticking 'allow' boxes for my account.
- Used Get-Acl to check subfolders and files were also changed.
- Have scanned the "offline scanner" folder with MBAM and Defender, no threats found.
- sfc /verifyfile= ... doesn't seem to work for the contents of the "offline scanner" folder.
- The reason I opened the folder: looking for scan logs.

I should have said why the permissions seemed to change.
Before clicking Continue, the Security tab of the folder properties said "You must have Read permissions to view the properties of this object". Afterwards my user account had Full Control of the folder and contents.

The pop-up said " You don't currently have permission to access this folder. Click Continue to permanently get access to this folder."

A few years old, but this seemed to be the way it was.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/950934/when-you-click-continue-for-folder-access-in-windows-explorer-your-use

Comment: clicking Continue does not change any permissions, so it is still safe from most malware.

Comment: I added info about why it seemed the permissions changed.